# MS Graph API: Access denied when trying to create a list, even with Sites.ReadWrite.All application permissions

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-create?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), to create a list, a `Sites.ReadWrite.All` application permission is needed.

I have an Azure app with exactly that permission:
[image: App registration]

Yet, when trying to create a list **I still get access denied**.

```
403 : Forbidden
[...]

[Some information was truncated for brevity, enable debug logging for more details]
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: accessDenied
Error message: Access denied
```

The full output can be found [here](http://gist.github.com/hariso/5c31c0daef1929d019ba4dce8a48e811). The complete code which reproduces the behavior can be found [here](https://github.com/hariso/graph-api-create-list). The application requires [access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service). The access token is generated through a client assertion flow.

**The question is**: What's wrong here? Is it the documentation which is outdated? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you please share the truncated information of error as well? Have you tested in POSTMAN? Are you seeing the same error?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Shiva. Here's the full output: https://gist.github.com/hariso/5c31c0daef1929d019ba4dce8a48e811 The same endpoint, with the same token, gives the same result in Postman. I've "debugged" the token (using jwt.io) and it contains the "Sites.ReadWrite.All" role.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity I've added some additional info above.

Comment: I was also able to reproduce your issue. Will get back to you on this.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity Were you able to get to some more info about this?

Comment: Sorry Haris, no response from PG team yet. Will update this thread once we here back.